# What's the best way to initialize an STL array from a C-style array?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

What's the best way to copy data from a C API that returns a pointer to an STL container?

In this example the data for a 4x4 matrix is returned as a pointer:

```cpp
double* m = get_mat4x4();
std::array<double, 16> m2;
std::copy(m, m + 16, m2);
```

Is there a better way to initialize the array or copy the data?

Comment: Define _better_ please. Are you unhappy that you need three lines to do this?

Comment: If you're asking in terms of speed, the code you write is merely a description of what you want to do.  The compiler can optimize the code so that it looks nothing like your original description, so long as the resulting optimized code comes out to the same result.

Comment: You can pass `m, m + 16` directly to ctor instead of calling `std::copy()`